# Definition of semi-simple Lie algebras in Chevalley and Eilenberg's thesis

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I am reading Chevalley and Eilenberg's "*Cohomology Theory of Lie Groups and Lie Algebras*" and I get some confusion. In page 106 the authors write

> If every represention of $L$ if fully reducible then $L$ is called semi-simple

I think the property holds only for finite dimensional representions. I wonder where I misunderstood. Thanks!

Comment: Chevalley and Eilenberg assume finite-dimensional (see introduction). Page $87$: Given an arbitrary finite-dimensional vector space F over R, ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However it seems that this sentence is not talking about representions.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But I don't find this assumption in the introduction.